# Get a variable from a linked page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Apologies for my ignorance, I'm new to JavaScript and web development in general.

I have a page (A) that links to another page (B).

Inside page (B) I have a bit of code with some variables defined in JS like this:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var big_string = "I am a large string";

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to write a greasemonkey script that will get the value of big_string and append it to a var in page (A). I *feel* like I ought to be able to get big_string from inside (A) since I have a link to (B) but I can't find any examples of how to do this. Is what I'm trying to do possible or am I going about this in the completely wrong way?

Comment: check this out `http://browserify.org/` it'll help you to include the js of page 2 to page 1

Comment: @NEO-xx, try reading the question again. Browserify won't help in this instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "linked to"? You mean via an `<a>` tag, or is it a popup, or are you referring to different tabs on a browser?

Comment: Linked as in I have the href from the <a> tag on page (A) that points to page (B).

Comment: Your case is *probably* simpler than the duplicate, but you did not provide enough details for us to be sure. The linked approach will work in almost every case. For your situation you would either message-back `unsafeWindow.big_string` or parse the appropriate `<script>` tag.  But you need to **provide enough information for us to duplicate your situation.** Provide links to the target page(s) if possible.